Can we find (and understand) the ordering functions used in the various output forms?
Can we use (and perhaps even understand) the sorting functions used in the various output forms (such as OutputForm, TraditionalForm, TeXForm, etc...).

This is motivated by the fact that I would like to change how some expressions are sorted in TeXForm so that I can export them in a nice order. I'm not looking to order them by hand (as has been explained in other answers before). I'm looking to adjust the sorting.
For example with
sortFunction = Reverse;
Format[test[args___], TeXForm] := 
 StringRiffle[sortFunction@{args}, " "]

I'd like to be able to use an output form that I already like as a basis. (After which I can perform some more sorting if it isn't exactly what I want yest.)
